# Does Block.one have more funding than Ethereum Foundation?

Tags: ethereum, block.one

I'm curious to who has more funding. Block.one or Ethereum Foundation? Are there other organizations that serve the role of increasing adoption for eos or ethereum foundation? Also how do they differ?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO. Perhaps, you can ask this on a Reddit forum.

Comment: If this question and its answers are not primarily opinion based, it is ok to ask something like this - also if they are not development related (check the [EOSIO Meta discussion](https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-this-exchange-for-developer-questions-only)).